# How do I add class to sidebar on $_GET

Tags: php, css, function, xhtml

I got a problem to get correct class to my sidebar.

```
function sidebar_class($var) 
{
    if (isset($_GET['page']) == $var )
    echo ' class="selected"';
}
```

My URL will looks like

```
http://domain.com/index.php?go=users
http://domain.com/index.php?go=settings
http://domain.com/index.php?go=backup
```

My sidebar

```
<ul>
 <li<?php sidebar_class('users'); ?>><a href='index.php?go=users'>Users</a></li>
 <li<?php sidebar_class('settings'); ?>><a href='index.php?go=settings'>Settings</a></li>
 <li<?php sidebar_class('backup'); ?>><a href='index.php?go=backup'>Backup</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now all my sidebar class being `<li class="selected">`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wrong function... try:

```
function sidebar_class($var) 
{
    if (isset($_GET['go']) && $_GET['go'] == $var )
        echo ' class="selected"';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check value of go instead of page. right?

```
function sidebar_class($var) 
{
    if (isset($_GET['go']) == $var )
    echo ' class="selected"';
}
```